# Moving skewness/k​urtosis/rm​s/autocorr​elation for time series. Fast Implementation. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, parallel-processing

I want an extremely fast implementation of computing a moving window skewness over my time series, as I have to do this for a lot of different window sizes and the application is time critical (and similarly do this for other measures such as kurtosis, rms, autocorrelation etc. Here I focus on skewness.

I have an array of time series data `state_timeseries` (~10,000,000) and the corresponding time values.
I want to use a window size (~300,000 - 4,000,000) and a step size of (= 1% of corresponding window size = 3000 - 40000) to find the moving window skewness of this time series.
This is to be done for all window sizes from the following list:

```matlab
window_size_list = floor(linspace(300000, 4000000, 200));
step_size_list = floor(window_size_list * (1 / 100));
```

For parallel computing I have 16 workers with ~130GB RAM and the GeForce RTX 2070 Super 8GB in size.

Is it possible to get good speed gains if I make these calculations in C++ instead? (I don't know C++, but reading online makes me think this). Then get the generated moving window skewness timeseries back into MATLAB for further processing?

**My Current Implementation:**

Currently, I am simply looping over (both window sizes and for each window the moving window) as follows (but this is quite slow):

```matlab
% Dummy data of equal length
state_timeseries = randn(1, 10000000);
time = 1: length(state_timeseries);

total_window_count = 200; % 200 as used above

window_size_list = floor(linspace(300000, 4000000, total_window_count));
step_size_list = floor(window_size_list * (1 / 100));

for k = 1: total_window_count

    % Set window size and step size to calculate the corresponding EWS timeseries
    window_size = window_size_list(k);
    window_step = step_size_list(k);

    % Generate EWS timeseries for particular window size
    Data_skewness_timeseries{k} = sk_timeseries_func(time, state_timeseries, window_size, window_step);
    
end
```

```matlab
function Data = sk_timeseries_func(time, state_timeseries, window_size, window_step)

    % Use GPU if available
    gpu_available = canUseGPU();
    if gpu_available == 1
        time = gpuArray(time);
        state_timeseries = gpuArray(state_timeseries);
    end
    
    % Get the indices where windows start and the corresponding times at which they end.
    % This is to specify the skewness of a window at the time value at the end of the window.
    window_idx = 1: window_step: (length(time) - window_size + 1);
    time_window_ends_idx = window_idx + window_size - 1;
    time_window_ends = time(time_window_ends_idx);
    
    sk_timeseries = zeros(1, length(time_window_ends));
    
    for i_window = 1: length(window_idx)
        timeseries_window_data = state_timeseries(window_idx(i_window): window_idx(i_window) + window_size - 1);
        
        sk_timeseries(i_window) = skewness(timeseries_window_data);
    
    end
    
    Data.time_window_ends = time_window_ends;
    Data.sk_timeseries = sk_timeseries;
    
end
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's slow. I've updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting in C++ or another compiled language will not give you the 100x speed up that you would have gotten 20 years ago. Depending on the exact MATLAB code, you might get a 2x speed up, or you might get slower code.

You’re using the GPU. I don’t know its effect in this program (did you compare without?), in C++ you might be able to control that more precisely, if you know how to do that, and therefore get very efficient code. Again, I don’t know how efficient your current GPU code is, I don’t have experience with that.

If you have the Parallel Processing Toolbox, you should make the loop over `total_window_count` parallel (do use a thread-based parallel pool).

In general, the large speed improvements always come from a better algorithm. [Note that you can compute skewness on line.](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/skewness_kurtosis/). This means you can remove the samples at the start of your window, and add new ones at the end, when you move the window over. This potentially saves 99% of the computations you do (assuming 1% window length shifts). This does require implementing your own on-line skewness function, rather than using the built-in function from MATLAB.